# How to get video start time with libvlc

Tags: video, ffmpeg, libvlc

I'm trying to sync multiple videos based on the real time they were saved at.

For playing the video, I ended up with libvlc, but now i'm unable to read the metadata that contains the time at which the video starts.

I would use the start time to calculate offsets for videos, so that i can sync them with each other.

I created the video from an rtsp stream with the ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -i <stream path> -timestamp now output.mp4
```

looking at the file with ffprobe, I can see that it contains the correct timestamp in creation_time.

But this I am unable to read with libvlc.

Is there a way to save the real wallclock start time on the video in such a way that i can read it from libvlc?

Other suggestions that tell me how to sync two videos are welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible to do. On another project we were trying to get the real-time clock data from an RTSP feed, but only relative clock data can be retrieved, nothing that it includes a system time. You may want to check the libvlc forums. I couldn't find an answer there, but they are pretty good at responding to questions within a week.

Comment: It's not possible, I named the file with a timestamp and parse the name when loading.